# Oracle query between two timestamps not returning records

Tags: oracle, systimestamp

I am trying to get all records in the database that have an update date between the interval of systimestamp -15 minutes, to the current systimestamp.

So what I do is:

```
and (CAST (update_date AS TIMESTAMP)  at time zone 'UTC') BETWEEN  (cast((systimestamp - interval '15' minute) at time zone 'UTC' as timestamp)) AND  (cast((systimestamp) at time zone 'UTC' as timestamp))
```

If I take them separate for a specific record:

```
(CAST (update_date AS TIMESTAMP)  at time zone 'UTC') -> 26-APR-18 01.10.16.000000000 AM UTC
(cast((systimestamp - interval '15' minute) at time zone 'UTC' as timestamp)) -> 26-APR-18 12.57.04.136000000 AM
(cast((systimestamp) at time zone 'UTC' as timestamp)) -> 26-APR-18 01.12.04.136000000 AM
```

Basically the first one is between the two other ones, so the query should return a record, but it doesn't. Any help?

Comment: You'll notice that the two based on timestamp are no longer in UTC (note the first one has it at the end of the value). This is because you are casting your properly formed timestamps to timestamp again, which loses that form. Remove unnecessary casts and this should work fine.

Comment: What is the data type of `update_date`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit it is of type date, but it does store the timestamp though

Comment: I assiume thex are all UTC times?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit it's PST actually, so I transform it to UTC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SYSTIMESTAMP](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions173.htm) returns a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` value.

Assuming `update_date` is also a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` you don't need any cast at all, simply run

```
update_date BETWEEN SYSTIMESTAMP - interval '15' minute AND SYSTIMESTAMP
```

Comparisons are always done internally in UTC, see [Datetime and Interval Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG250):

> Oracle Database performs all timestamp arithmetic in UTC time. For
>   TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE data, Oracle Database converts the
>   datetime value from the database time zone to UTC and converts back to
>   the database time zone after performing the arithmetic. For TIMESTAMP
>   WITH TIME ZONE data, the datetime value is always in UTC, so no
>   conversion is necessary.

As you have `DATE` values in `PST` (nb, how do you handle daylight-saving-times in this case?) you would run

```
FROM_TZ(CAST(update_date AS TIMESTAMP), 'PST') BETWEEN SYSTIMESTAMP - interval '15' minute AND SYSTIMESTAMP
```